# Pandas read_csv works but pyarrow doesnt

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pyarrow

I have a csv file, which is tab separated. The following code:

```
import numpy as np
import sys
import pyarrow.csv as pa_csv
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(sys.argv[1],sep='\t',header=0,dtype='object')
parse_options = pa_csv.ParseOptions(delimiter='\t')
data = pa_csv.read_csv(sys.argv[1], parse_options=parse_options)
```

fails on the pyarrow read:

Having looked at the data I have been given it seems the nunmber of columns varies:

```
awk '{print NF}' data.csv:

200651
200651
200651
200653
200651
200651
200651
```

How does pandas handle this case, and why doesnt pyarrow do the same?

Can pyarrow be forced to behave in the same way?

**EDIT**

The number of columns doesnt vary. I didnt use the tab as a delimter to awk.

```
awk -F'\t' '{print NF}'
200669
200669
200669
200669
200669
200669
200669
200669
```

so what is causing the error?

**Update**

adding

```
read_options=pa_csv.ReadOptions(block_size=1e9)
```

solved the issue. I guess it is down to the number of columns being large.

Comment: Are you checking if the extra fields are quoted or not?

Comment: There are no quotation marks in the csv file